# How do i include filename in the hyperlink in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to include a link after the picture, to copy that picture into an other catalog.
The code scans a catalog for pictures and displays them on a page, newest on top.

```
$folder = $cam.'/grabs/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
if ($sort == 'Nye') { 
    usort($files, create_function('$b,$a', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));
}

$count = count($files);
echo '</font><table>';
echo "<font color='white'> $count bilder";

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<a name="'.$i.'" href="#'.$i.'"><img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a>';
    echo substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
    echo '<a href="move.php?movefile='.$i.'&movefolder='.$folder.'"> - Save</a>' ;
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

My problem is that i do not know how to get the filname instead of $i in movefile='.$i.

I have tried to put in $files but that gives me an error message.

Comment: Aren't you doing that already in previous line?

Comment: _Small Point_ The <font> tag has been deprecated for years. You should instead get used to styling with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned a lot today.
The glob( will take every picture and give it a number $i
The original .$i. Returns a line number. (As stated in one of the comments, thanks for the hint.)

So, to get the filename, you have to add $files before the $i to get the right one.
The answer was:

.$files[$i].

```
echo '<a href="move.php?movefile= '.$files[$i].&movefolder='.$folder.'"> - Save</a>' ;
```